# How can I edit the windows registry through Ubuntu?

Tags: windows

Recently I downloaded a program on windows, and I think it installed a key-logger. I quickly went to Ubuntu, and deleted the program files from there.

I am quite sure that it is gone, but I must have deleted some file that is associated to the windows login (Which I don't know how, since I only deleted the the program's folder from the PrgramFilesx86 directory),because now when I login to windows, it says "loging in" then it flashes grey, then logs out.

I looked up answers to this question, and it seemed like you needed to edit the windows registry. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to do this from ubuntu. I saw a post that said you needed to install , but their instructions on how to edit the actual registry did not work. I was wondering if anyone could help me fix my problem.

Comment: This link: http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/Hacking%20the%20Windows%20Registry%20with%20chntpw.html does not work

Comment: never mind, it works now. I will try it and get back to you